# My database reference does not show up in the tree

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I have a method that I cdreated called getAssignedCustomerLocation that creates a database reference with the variable name assignedCustomerRef but,that database reference does not actually show up in my firebase console. No node is created on the actual console for it. Code below

```
 public void getAssignedCustomerLocation(){
        String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        DatabaseReference assignedCustomerRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("customerRequest").child(userId).child("l");
        assignedCustomerRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    List<Object> map = (List<Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                    double locationLat = 0;
                    double locationLong =0;
                    if (map.get(0)!=null) {
                        locationLat= Double.parseDouble(map.get(0).toString());

                    }
                    if (map.get(1)!=null){
                        locationLong = Double.parseDouble(map.get(1).toString());
                    }
                    LatLng driverLatLong = new LatLng(locationLat,locationLong);
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(driverLatLong).title("your driver"));



                }

            }
```

Comment: Can you show your db structure?

Comment: addValueEventListener is used to read from firebase db, not to write.

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have used is to read from firebase. If you want to write a new node to the db use below.

```
String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference assignedCustomerRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("customerRequest").child(userId).child("l");
assignedCustomerRef.setValue("YOUR_DATA");
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a node in the database you need to use [`setValue()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#setValue(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object,%20com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.CompletionListener)), so you can do the following:

```
DatabaseReference assignedCustomerRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("customerRequest").child(userId);
assignedCustomerRef.child("l").setValue("your driver");
```